# Testing error handling when writing a csv file

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I would like to set `ErrorMode = ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue` so I can process errors after a CSV file has been written.

How can I generate row level errors artificially when calling `WriteStream()` so that I can test my error handling?

In particular I would like to find out whether the `AfterWriteRecord` event is fired if a row errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code there are a few ways:

You call `WriteStream()` with an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is your FileHelpers record class. So in your test, create a `List<T>`, but add null to it as one of the records. This will cause `WriteStream()` to raise a `BadUsageException`.

Alternatively, you could add an `OnProgress` event in which you throw an exception.

You could also throw an exception from a `BeforeWriteEvent` or an `AfterWriteEvent`.

You could attach a [custom field converter](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/example_advanced.html) which throws an exception in the `FieldToString()` override.

Any of the above exceptions will be trapped by the `SaveAndContinue` option.